# Powershell script to run Selenium Test Cases

Tags: powershell, selenium, jenkins, octopus-deploy

We are having Jenkins on windows server. We deploy the application from Jenkins to Octopus Server. Octopus server is present on another server. If the deployment is successful, Octopus has to trigger a Powershell script and this script in turn has to run the Selenium test cases present in Jenkins. If the deployment is failed, this script has to return a "Deployment Failure" message to Jenkins.
So can anyone help me out in this Powershell scripting as i am new to Powershell.

TIA

Comment: are you deploying to octopus using octo.exe or interface?

Comment: using octo.exe, i package my files and deploy that package to Octopus server

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/d16a390e36ec3ba54cd5e3f760cfb59e